# Numpy: How to quickly replace equal values in an matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Lets say we have a rank 2 array `a` with `n` entries that contain integer values in `{0,1,2,...,m}`. Now for each of those integers I want to find the indices of the entries of `a` with this value (called `index_i, index_j` in the following examples). (So what I'm looking for is like `np.unique(...,return_index=True)` but for 2d arrays and with the possibility to return *all* indices of each unique value.)

A naive approach would involve using boolean indexing which would result in `O(m*n)` operations (see below), but I'd like to only have `O(n)` operations. While I found a solution to do that, I feel like there should be a built in method or at least something that simplifies this - or that would at least remove these ugly loops:

```python
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,2,1],[2,2,1]])
m = a.max()


#"naive" in O(n*m)
i,j = np.mgrid[range(a.shape[0]), range(a.shape[1])]
index_i = [[] for _ in range(m+1)]
index_j = [[] for _ in range(m+1)]
for k in range(m+1):
  index_i[k] = i[a==k]
  index_j[k] = j[a==k]

#all the zeros:
print(a[index_i[0], index_j[0]])
#all the ones:
print(a[index_i[1], index_j[1]])
#all the twos:
print(a[index_i[2], index_j[2]])


#"sophisticated" in O(n)

index_i = [[] for _ in range(m+1)]
index_j = [[] for _ in range(m+1)]
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
  for j in range(a.shape[1]):
    index_i[a[i,j]].append(i)
    index_j[a[i,j]].append(j)

#all the zeros:
print(a[index_i[0], index_j[0]])
#all the ones:
print(a[index_i[1], index_j[1]])
#all the twos:
print(a[index_i[2], index_j[2]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zZFBbsMgFET3nOIr2ZgWWba7i5Qz9AAIRV81jcEBI0zbuJd3IU4cp4266qKrL828GYnBDaHp7NM4KuM6H8C@GTcA9mAdQdjGk6P3OGScF6xgpWDxVqdbna6gxEQOc4PHjBJC1iuL6l2uQFl4zuyDoUQxPVWZvVc192j3MsO8b9BJXgjK4FYqBRVE2VoedyoGORfw2nnYpcqJNI/ljOjfkCS2t@KGAJzLeStiWHHcblsxy3qS9VkmazwcIDQSPqXv@g1xXtmQIb@UFILNySINMgc6K@/w5YIvb/jwca@/WvBV4tPIfeca1Qf1gkHWl7Gj9Xezqau4@Ku0XnL1T7ec3Ou68QlMC5Gjc9LWmaILV393Nf1/S4/jFw)

(Note that I will need these indices for write access later, that is, for replacing the values stored in the array. But between these operations I do need to the 2d structure.)

Comment: maybe [`numpy.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) ? something like `[np.argwhere(a == x) for x in np.unique(a)]` ..?

Comment: What would be the final output be like? Considering that there could be variable number of elements, that could complicate things when looking to remove loops.

Comment: @ChrisA Thanks that is close to what I'm looking for, at least it simplifies the code. The problem with this is that you still need `O(n*m)` operations, as you compare every value `x` to the whole input array.

Comment: @Divakar Ideally a collections of lists of indices, where each of those lists corresponds to one value. (Just like `index_i, index_j` in my example.)

Comment: Gentle reminder - Any feedback on the posted solution?

Comment: Sorry, I was only able to test it quickly without having had the time to understand what is going on. It will take a while until I can work on this again. I do appreciate your answer but I just lack the time to go through it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one based on `sorting` with the intention of having minimal work when iterating to save as a dictionary that has keys being the unique elements and the values as the indices -

```
shp = a.shape
idx = a.ravel().argsort()
idx_sorted = np.c_[np.unravel_index(idx,shp)]
count = np.bincount(a.ravel())
valid_idx = np.flatnonzero(count!=0)
cs = np.r_[0,count[valid_idx].cumsum()]
out = {e:idx_sorted[i:j] for (e,i,j) in zip(valid_idx,cs[:-1],cs[1:])}
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [155]: a
Out[155]: 
array([[0, 2, 6],
       [0, 2, 6],
       [2, 2, 1]])

In [156]: out
Out[156]: 
{0: array([[0, 0],
        [1, 0]]), 1: array([[2, 2]]), 2: array([[0, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 0],
        [2, 1]]), 6: array([[0, 2],
        [1, 2]])}
```

If all integers in the sequence are covered in the array, we could simplify it a bit -

```
shp = a.shape
idx = a.ravel().argsort()
idx_sorted = np.c_[np.unravel_index(idx,shp)]
cs = np.r_[0,np.bincount(a.ravel()).cumsum()]
out = {iterID:idx_sorted[i:j] for iterID,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(cs[:-1],cs[1:]))}
```